# Columna null al importar datos de excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Estoy importando datos de un archivo excel a mi base de datos desde laravel y me encuentro con un problema con el `first or create` me sale el siguiente error:

`Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tipo_nombre' cannot be null (SQL: insert into 'tbl_tipo_instrumento' ('tipo_nombre') values (?))`

El codigo de como estoy haciendo el `import` es el siguiente:

```
public function model(array $row)
{

    //dd($row['tipoinstrumento']); ver si el dato llega

    //Si no encuentra el dato en la tabla lo crea

    $tipo = tbl_tipo_instrumento::firstOrCreate(
        ['tipo_nombre' => $row['tipoinstrumento']],//busca
        ['tipo_nombre'=>$row['tipoinstrumento']] //crea
    );
    $marca = tbl_marca::firstOrCreate(
        ['mar_nombre' => $row['marca']],
        ['mar_nombre'=>$row['marca']]
    );

    $id = Auth::id(); //trae el id del usuario logeado

    return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row['codigo'],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row['observacioninicial'],
        'ins_proximaCalibracion'=>$row['proximacalibracion'],
        'ins_fechaUltimaCalibracion'=>$row['ultimacalibracion'],
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row['claseoexactitud'],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row['nserie'],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row['divoescala'],
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row['consecutivointerno'],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row['observaciones'],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row['observacionfinal'],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row['magnitud'],
        'ins_modelo' => $row['modelo'],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row['codigoactividad'],
        'ins_area' => 'null',
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $id,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
    ]);
}
```

Probe con `dd( )` para ver si el dato llegaba y si llega correctamente, no entiendo porque puede ser el fallo en mi modelo tengo lo siguiente:

```
class tbl_tipo_instrumento extends Model
{

public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = 'tipo_id';
public $table="tbl_tipo_instrumento";
protected $fillable = ['tipo_nombre'];
protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Lo mas curioso es que estuve trabajando bien y sin modificar el codigo dejo de funcionar, como podria solucionarlo?

Gracias

Comment: El `dd()` te muestra el dato de la primer fila o de todas?

Comment: Puse `dd($row['tipoinstrumento'])` y el dato que me arrojo es el que esta en la celda osea balanza, tengo una fila de encabezado y una de datos nada mas.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ No te entendi muy bien lo que quieres ver, el codigo que me envias no funciona en la version `3.1`hasta donde tengo entendido no? No se si sirva pero puse el `dd()` para que me mostrara todas las filas y las toma sin problema

Comment: Ok, lo que quería ver es cuántas **cuantas filas reconoce la librería**. Entonces que te muestra el `dd()` de todas las filas?. De todas maneras el mensaje de error es claro, y viendo el código, en alguna fila para el índice  `'tipoinstrumento'` tienes un valor nulo. Puedes evitarlo de varias maneras, solo tienes que leer la documentación y seguir las instrucciones, por ejemplo [Saltar filas](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html#skipping-rows)

Comment: Aaaa ya, claro no tuve en cuenta eso, me fije y habia una fila = null, gracias por aclararme eso